# CGAL cmake on ubuntu 16.04 fails

Tags: cgal

I am trying to run the code of PU-GAN(https://github.com/liruihui/PU-GAN),you can get the program(evaluation code) in (https://github.com/liruihui/PU-GAN).but I am failed to camake CGAL libaray. i get following error:

```
    (tf) li@li-System-Product-Name:/media/li/1d105677-e036-4fa4-8e37-124cb400f24d/user/shenbin/PU-GAN-master/evaluation_code$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.0") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")  
-- Using header-only CGAL
-- Targetting Unix Makefiles
-- Using /usr/bin/c++ compiler.
-- Found GMP: /home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/libgmp.so  
-- Found MPFR: /home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/libmpfr.so  
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found suitable version "1.58.0", minimum required is "1.48")  
-- Boost include dirs: /usr/include
-- Boost libraries:    
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
-- Build type: 
-- USING CXXFLAGS = ' -fopenmp '
-- USING EXEFLAGS = '-Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib -L/home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib '
CMake Warning at /usr/local/lib/cmake/CGAL/CGAL_enable_end_of_configuration_hook.cmake:99 (message):
  =======================================================================

  CGAL performance notice:

  The variable CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is set to "".  For performance reasons, you
  should set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to "Release".

  Set CGAL_DO_NOT_WARN_ABOUT_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to TRUE if you want to disable
  this warning.

  =======================================================================
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9999 (CGAL_run_at_the_end_of_configuration)


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /media/li/1d105677-e036-4fa4-8e37-124cb400f24d/user/shenbin/PU-GAN-master/evaluation_code


    (tf) li@li-System-Product-Name:/media/li/1d105677-e036-4fa4-8e37-124cb400f24d/user/shenbin/PU-GAN-master/evaluation_code$ make
Scanning dependencies of target evaluation
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/evaluation.dir/evaluation.cpp.o
/media/li/1d105677-e036-4fa4-8e37-124cb400f24d/user/shenbin/PU-GAN-master/evaluation_code/evaluation.cpp:19:50: fatal error: CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/measure.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/evaluation.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/evaluation.dir/evaluation.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/evaluation.dir/evaluation.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:77: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/evaluation.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/evaluation.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I cannot find a way to compile any of my CGAL Programyou

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a mismatch between compilers or mismatch between the CGAL library and compilers - your CMake has found the `cc` compiler **inside your `anaconda3` directory**:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/li/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

Different versions of `C` and `CXX` - that's not good. Please do not use the old compiler from the Anaconda distribution, and make sure both `C` and `CXX` compilers belong to the same (better the most recent) package.